# Splitting field over $\Bbb F_2$ with degree $8$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> How do I determine the splitting field of this  polynomial
> $x^8+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1$ over $\Bbb F_2$.

I had referred to other question answers on the website, but all of them are with a lower degree (degree $3$). I had tried factorizing the polynomial but not sure what to do next. Thanks

Comment: You say you tried factoring. Did you test for divisibility by an irreducible polynomial of degree 2, 3, or 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
f(x)=(x^3 + x^2 + 1)(x^3 + x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1).
$$
Then compare with

[Degree of splitting field of polynomial over a finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424708/degree-of-splitting-field-of-polynomial-over-a-finite-field?rq=1)

[Galois group of polynomials over finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295675/galois-group-of-polynomials-over-finite-fields)